# Url from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

How do I create dynamic urls from mysql database?

I have a subscription system, then i want to create pages for subscribers like `www.mydomain.com/subscriber1`
In that order. i know how to pull the data using `www.mydomain.com/subscribers?subs=ID`.

I have tried

```
<?php
    $url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    if (isset($_GET[url])) {
        $url2 = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i", "-", $_GET[url]);

    }
?>
```

Comment: What server are you using? (If Apache, take a look at `mod_rewrite`)

Comment: Am using Apache. Let me try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it by htaccess too.

here is the code

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# redirect "/section.php?id=xxx" to "/section/xxx"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/section\.php\?id=([0-9]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /section/%1? [R=301,L]

# internally rewrite "/section/xxx" to "/section.php?id=xxx"
RewriteRule ^section/([0-9]+)$ /section.php?id=$1 [L]
```

make sure mod_rewrite is enabled and htaccess files allowed in your Apache configuration.

Comment: Mohd, Thanks for taking your time to respond. I will give feedback when i test

Comment: I have tried... it has worked, but then when the page opens, all css stylesheet links are not working, making the page pullout without any styling, so ugly.

Comment: I guess you are using the relative path for including the assets, please use absolute path for it.
like if CSS is in a directory "resource/css/main.css" to include it write as "<?= base_url ?>/resource/css/main.css"
and there will be no problem in loading it

Comment: Mohd. Thank you. it worked well. I used "<?=base_url?> and everything worked out fine. Thanks alot

Comment: then please mark the answer with tick so that others can benefit from it, and upvote it if possible.

Answer (score -1):

Here you go.

```
function links($text){

    // replace non letter or digits by -
    $text = preg_replace('~[^\pL\d]+~u', '-', $text);

    // transliterate
    $text = iconv('utf-8', 'us-ascii//TRANSLIT', $text);

    // remove unwanted characters
    $text = preg_replace('~[^-\w]+~', '', $text);

    // trim
    $text = trim($text, '-');

    // remove duplicate -
    $text = preg_replace('~-+~', '-', $text);

    // lowercase
    $text = strtolower($text);

    if (empty($text)) {
    return 'n-a';
    };

    return $text;

};

echo links('How to create dynamic urls from mysql database?'); 
//how-to-create-dynamic-urls-from-mysql-database
```

Comment: How is this related to OPs question? Also maybe next time add a little more info on what your code does